# Multiple operation in same sql

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I have a table with columns `RECID,regionID, areaID ,UserID ,AppNo, NextAppNo`(Accepts null)

and data is as follows (NextApp is not null in the first row only):

```
1,102,Ar-1,xyz,1,1
2,102,Ar-1,qwe,2
3,102,Ar-1,fgh,3
4,102,Ar-1,yuyi,4
```

**1) Add a record**

Now I want to add another record:

- First I get the max number of APPID `where areaID = Ar-1 and regionID =102` (Java)
- Then, if max appNo is 0, add nextappNo, otherwise do nothing
- Then insert into db

Is it possible to do this in one query?

**2) Delete a record**

In another query i want to delete the first record:

- First I select data `where areaID = 'Ar-1' and regionID =102`
- Then in a loop (Java) I check if Recid is the same id I want to delete
- From there onward I update the the column approver and also, if the record which we are going to delete has `approverNO = 1`, then also update the next approver to one of the next record
- Then delete the record from table.

Comment: for point #2 why do need to go through a loop? Cant you make a select query such that the row you fetch has a recid = to the one you have to delete and having areaid='Ar-1' and regionId = 102 ??

Comment: You should try to describe what you really want to achieve. Your description, being imperative in spirit, is a bit confusing in the context of SQL.

Comment: @TheUnknown i have to update the apprNo e.g if rec with aprpno 2 is delete than frome there onwards apprNo 3 becomes apprNo 2 and appNo 4 becomes 3 and so on , and if this is first approver that is deleted than also add next approver no to 1

Comment: @Ingo this is mix of sql an java

Comment: @Haider - Doesn't matter. If you can't express the general idea of what you want in plain, simple english, you're probably doomed. You seem to think too much in terms of a certain implementation you have already decided on, this makes it hard for me to find you what you really want.

Comment: @Ingo , niclely said, i want to do step 1 in same query if possible and also step 2

Comment: Go with procedures so you can do it with some easy steps...

Comment: Why store continuous `AppNo` values at all? All that's needed is **sequential** `AppNo`s, and ROW_NUMBER can supply continuous numbers without ever needing to change any values in the rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql procedure to do it. It will be easier when you execute that single procedure with any type of operation such as insert,delete,update, etc.,

Comment: so if i do that , i have to loop the records in sp in order to reassign the ApproverNo sequence.

Comment: Yes but using a single sp you can do as many operations you need.

Comment: any functionality available in db2 where i can assign the sequence with some condition